# Is "to know who were the people that..." correct in this sentence?

Tags: subject-auxiliary-inversion

> Most of us when we have seen houses which were picturesquely situated, and wore a look of unusual beauty and comfort, **have felt a desire to know who were the people that lived in them.**

I suppose that last phrase "to know who were the people that..." is wrong, "to know who the people that lived in them were." is correct.
Do I misunderstand??

Comment: You are right. See the [penthouse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penthouse_principle) )))

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Another correct version would be

> . . . to know who the people were who lived in them.

You should be aware, however, that in informal contexts (including the chattier sort of journalism), the inverted form (*who were the people*) is not uncommon and will not raise any eyebrows.